# set multiple namespaces with XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, infopath, xmltextwriter

I'm trying to create an infopath form XML file. I was initially following this example [programmatically-create-infopath-form-console-app](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/programmatically-create-infopath-form-console-app.htm) but I'm getting issues with multiple namespaces.

Here's some namespaces in my infopath form XML file

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" 
xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types"
```

For the most part, when I'm following the example, everything is going well until I read the people picker portion of the XML File.

What I want:

```
<my:Updated_By>
    <pc:Person>
        <pc:DisplayName></pc:DisplayName>
        <pc:AccountId></pc:AccountId>
        <pc:AccountType></pc:AccountType>
    </pc:Person>
</my:Updated_By>
```

What I did (1):

```
        string myNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2007-09-02T01:11:44";
        ...
        writer.WriteStartElement("my", "myFields", myNamespace);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "pc", null, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls");

        ...

        writer.WriteStartElement("my", "Updated_By", myNamespace);
        writer.WriteStartElement("pc", "Person");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("pc", "DisplayName");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("pc", "AccountId");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("pc", "AccountType");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        ...
```

What I got (1):

```
<my:Updated_By>
    <pc xmlns="Person" />
    <pc xmlns="DisplayName" />
    <pc xmlns="AccountId" />
    <pc xmlns="AccountType" />
</my:Updated_By>
```

I'm not sure if the "xmlns=" makes any difference in the XML file but I would prefer for it to look as close as possible to the XML File produced by infopath

What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Xml Linq.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                            "<my:Updated_By xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                              " xmlns:pc=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls\"" +
                              " xmlns:dms=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types\"" +
                              " xmlns:my=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2007-09-02T01:11:44\">" +
                            "</my:Updated_By>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace pcNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("pc");

            string name = "John";
            string id = "123";
            string type = "person";

            root.Add(new XElement(pcNs + "Person",
                new XElement(pcNs + "DisplayName", name),
                new XElement(pcNs + "AccountId", id),
                new XElement(pcNs + "AccountType", type)
                ));

            doc.Save("filename");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The xml you posted did not have the names 'my' defined which may have been the issue.  My xml has 'my' defined.

Comment: it was defined in the line `string myNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2007-09-02T01:11:44";` which seemed to work for the most part like `<my:Updated_By>`. when I tried to define it as an attribute, I would receive an error message.

Comment: I just ran your original code and found you need to more lines at end 1) writer.WriteEndElement();
           2) writer.Flush();